# Is the one-time pad still perfectly secret if all-zero keys are excluded?

Tags: one-time-pad, perfect-secrecy

I'm trying to solve this question related to one-time pads and perfect secrecy:

[image: question]

My solution is: I assumed that the current message space is  $M = \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^l$ and the new keyspace after removing $0^l$ from the set is $K = \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^l - 0^l$. Since clearly $|K| < |M|$, the new scheme is not perfectly secret.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Do you expect anything but a simple "yes" as the answer?

Comment: Hi Mitch and welcome. Just a small remark: try to make your titles as precise as possible; there are many ways in which the OTP's perfect secrecy can be broken: the title should clearly indicate what is asked.

Comment: Similar question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3992/18700

Answer (score 5):

Yes your solution is correct; the flawed OTP scheme is no longer perfectly secret if there are fewer keys than messages.

Once you remove the all zero key the property
$$
\mathbb{P}[M=m|C=c]=\mathbb{P}[M=m],\qquad \forall m,\forall c,\quad(1)
$$
required for perfect secrecy will no longer necessarily

Comment: I've removed the word "also" from the second part of your answer, could you check if this still good for your answer?